# Scrapy cookies not passing through multiple callbacks

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

I'm trying to get the locations from the Valero store locator. Using the chrome dev tools I see the following requests being made that relate to the data I ultimately need to get (the store locations). I'm not sure that I need to use all of these, but I'm including them all for reference.

***GET requests in DOC***

1. https://www.valero.com/en-us/ProductsAndServices/Consumers/StoreLocator

   - This is the url we see in chrome
   - Cookies and session information is set here
   - This is our start request

If we open up the dev tools and enter in a zipcode, we can look at the subsequent requests that made and how the data is returned.

2. https://www.valero.com/en-us/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvaleromaps%2Evalero%2Ecom%2Fhome%3FSPHostUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww%252Evalero%252Ecom%252Fen%252Dus%26SPHostTitle%3DValero%2520%252D%26SPAppWebUrl%3D%22%22%26SPLanguage%3Den%252DUS%26SPClientTag%3D1%26SPProductNumber%3D15%252E0%252E5047%252E1000%26SenderId%3DC46130E90&client_id=i%3A0i%2Et%7Cms%2Esp%2Eext%7Cb238ea69%2D5f91%2D445c%2D8a7d%2Df55c52f4d807%408bf952c5%2Def34%2D4ac6%2D822d%2D099871ec78da&anon=1

   - This is our parse_page1 request

**POST requests in DOC**

3. https://valeromaps.valero.com/home?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Evalero%2Ecom%2Fen%2Dus&SPHostTitle=Valero%20%2D&SPAppWebUrl=%22%22&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E5047%2E1000&SenderId=C46130E90

   - This is our parse_page2 request

**GET Request in XHR (do we need these?)**

4. https://www.valero.com/en-us/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Headerlinks')/items?$orderby=valeroOrder
5. https://www.valero.com/en-us/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FooterLinks')/items?$orderby=Group,Order0
6. https://www.valero.com/en-us/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Alerts')/items?$filter=Begins%20lt%20datetime%272018-09-19T16:51:52.140Z%27%20and%20Expires%20gt%20datetime%272018-09-19T16:51:52.140Z%27

**POST request in XHR**

7. https://valeromaps.valero.com/Home/GetDetailMaster?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.valero.com%2Fen-us

   - Don't think we need this request?
8. https://valeromaps.valero.com/Home/Search?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.valero.com%2Fen-us

   - This is the parse_page3 request where our data is returned
   - should be able to print a text response contain json and all of the store locations

[image: Valero data]

**Scrapy configuration notes**

•   “COOKIES_ENABLED” = True

•   Overriding scrapy default user-agent

My code below shows what I'm trying to do. Establish cookies in the start request, then callback to the subsequent requests that are being made trying to mimic what is happening on the website. The issue I'm running into is that the cookies get set after the start request, and then are passed in the parse_page1 request, but aren't passed in any of the subsequent requests, which I believe is causing the last request to return the message, "The requested URL was rejected." instead of the locations (although the response is 200). Note: parse_request() is just printing out the response and not actually parsing out locations--I'll update that once I know I can return the locations.

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://www.valero.com/en-us/ProductsAndServices/Consumers/StoreLocator'
    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'If-Modified-Since': 'Tue, 18 Sep 2018 19:11:50 GMT',
    }
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse_page1)

def parse_page1(self, response):
    r = response.text
    senderid = re.findall('spAppIFrameSenderInfo\[0\] = new Array\("(.*?)"', r)[0]
    url = 'https://www.valero.com/en-us/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvaleromaps%2Evalero%2Ecom%2Fhome%3FSPHostUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww%252Evalero%252Ecom%252Fen%252Dus%26SPHostTitle%3DValero%2520%252D%26SPAppWebUrl%3D%22%22%26SPLanguage%3Den%252DUS%26SPClientTag%3D1%26SPProductNumber%3D15%252E0%252E5047%252E1000%26SenderId%3D{0}&client_id=i%3A0i%2Et%7Cms%2Esp%2Eext%7Cb238ea69%2D5f91%2D445c%2D8a7d%2Df55c52f4d807%408bf952c5%2Def34%2D4ac6%2D822d%2D099871ec78da&anon=1'.format(senderid)
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method='POST', callback=self.parse_page2, meta={'senderid': senderid})

def parse_page2(self, response):
    senderid = response.meta['senderid']
    url = 'https://valeromaps.valero.com/home?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Evalero%2Ecom%2Fen%2Dus&SPHostTitle=Valero%20%2D&SPAppWebUrl=%22%22&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E5047%2E1000&SenderId={0}'.format(senderid)
    form = {
        'SPAppToken': '',
        'SPSiteUrl': 'https://www.valero.com/en-us',
        'SPSiteTitle': 'Valero -',
        'SPSiteLogoUrl': '',
        'SPSiteLanguage': 'en-US',
        'SPSiteCulture': 'en-US',
        'SPRedirectMessage': 'EndpointAuthorityMatches',
        'SPErrorCorrelationId': '',
        'SPErrorInfo': ''
    }
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method='POST', body=json.dumps(form), callback=self.parse_page3, meta={'senderid': senderid})

def parse_page3(self, response):
    url = 'https://valeromaps.valero.com/Home/Search?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.valero.com%2Fen-us'
    form = {
        'NEBound_Lat': '31.943824833980116',
        'NEBound_Long': '-94.08231139453125',
        'SWBound_Lat': '27.167727791447785',
        'SWBound_Long': '-103.12955260546875',
        'center_Lat': '29.555776312713952',
        'center_Long': '-98.605932',
    }
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method='POST', body=json.dumps(form), callback=self.parse)

def parse_request(self, response):
    print(response.text)
```

[image: Valero Runtime]

Is there a way to ensure that the cookies are persisting through each callback? I believe that this would help resolve the issue, however, if anyone notices a better way of obtaining the cookies that need to be send to the request that returns the data (#8 above) then I'd greatly appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the issue isn't about cookies, but the *headers*. You're using your custom headers **only in the first request**.

```
yield scrapy.Request(
  url=url, 
  headers=headers,  #      
  callback=self.parse_page1)

#...                                

yield scrapy.Request( #❓
   url=url, 
   method='POST', 
   callback=self.parse_page2, 
   meta={'senderid': senderid})`
```

You can define it as a `custom_settings` to make them work for every request in the spider:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    custom_settings = {
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
            'DNT': '1',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'If-Modified-Since': 'Tue, 18 Sep 2018 19:11:50 GMT',
        },
    }
```

More info about `custom_settings`: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.custom_settings

Comment: When I print response.request.headers for each callback, the headers are being returned. I was under the assumption that this means the headers are being passed on each subsequent request after being set in the first request. I previously had the default headers as part of my custom settings, however I thought it was redundant if they were passed along by default.

Comment: custom_settings = {
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': True,
        'COOKIES_DEBUG': True,
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'RetailScrape.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': None
        }
    }

Comment: Right now I have cookies on and I'm disabling the proxy to ensure that that is not the issue.

Comment: As a follow up I confirmed that the headers were not the issue by explicitly setting them in custom_settings.